# Android - spinner position value

Tags: android, spinner

Im using a Spinner in an AlertDialog as a Filter. When I reopen the Dialog after selecting an item, I want to select the chosen item from before by default. But some kind of magic is happening and I cant understand why the spinner is selecting the wrong item. The item list for the spinner is a String array with numbers from 4 to 42. `{"4","6",.."42"}`
When I select the first item `"4"` the position should be 0 and when I reopen the Dialog the exact item should be displayed. But instead it displays the item `"10"` on position 4.

Code Dialogfragment:

```
public class FittingSelectionDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

private String dTitle;

    private String[] list;

    private int position;

    private String filterItem;

    private List<String> chosenFilterItems;

    public interface FittingSelectionDialogListener {
        public void onChosenDialogItem(String filterStrings,int menuPosition);
    }

    FittingSelectionDialogListener mListener;


    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            final Spinner spinner2 = new Spinner(getActivity());
            final TextView label = new TextView(getActivity());
            final TextView label2 = new TextView(getActivity());
            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());

            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
            spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);

            if(chosenFilterItems.get(position).equals("")) {
                spinner2.setSelection(0);
            }
            else{
                spinner2.setSelection(Integer.valueOf(chosenFilterItems.get(position)));
            }

            label.setText("Rohr AD:");
            label.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorParkerBlack2));
            label.setTextSize(16);

            label.setPadding(60,0,40,0);

            label2.setText("mm");
            label2.setTextSize(16);
            label2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorParkerBlack2));

            dialog.setTitle(getdTitle());

            layout.addView(label);
            layout.addView(spinner2);
            layout.addView(label2);

            dialog.setView(layout);

            spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int spinner2Position, long id) {
                    filterItem = list[spinner2Position];
                    chosenFilterItems.set(position,String.valueOf(spinner2Position));
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),chosenFilterItems.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //correct value
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Bestätigen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    mListener.onChosenDialogItem(filterItem,position);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),chosenFilterItems.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//wrong value
                    dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.setNegativeButton("Abbrechen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    filterItem = "";
                    chosenFilterItems.set(position,"");
                    mListener.onChosenDialogItem(filterItem, position);
                }
            });
            return dialog.create();
    }
}
```

I made two Toasts inside the Listeners. The crazy thing is that in the OnItemSelectedListener the correct position value is displayed. In the PositiveButton OnClickListener is displaying the wrong value. Have you any idea?

Comment: Go into the debugger and see what's going on. It's kind of hard to do it without that.

Comment: I see that you use the List as a Map. Why don't use a map/HashMap anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I made a workaround by myself. I did not found the mistake by debugging. So I dont work with the position. I use the value to reselect the chosen Item. Not the best way, but works for this small itemlist.

Code:

```
if(chosenFilterItems.get(position).equals("")) {
    spinner2.setSelection(0);
}
else{
    for(int i=0; i<list.length;i++){
        if(list[i].equals(chosenFilterItems.get(position))){
            spinner2.setSelection(i);
        }
    }       
}

spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int spinner2Position, long id) {
    filterItem = list[spinner2Position];
}

dialog.setPositiveButton("Bestätigen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
    chosenFilterItems.set(position,filterItem);
    mListener.onChosenDialogItem(filterItem,position);
    dismiss();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and add some delay

```
int delay = 1000;
runOnUiThread (new Runnable () {
        @Override
        public void run () {

            if(chosenFilterItems.get(position).equals("")) {
                 spinner2.setSelection(0);
            } else {
                 Integer.valueOf(chosenFilterItems.get(position)));
            }
       }
}, delay);
```